# Are there any visual differences between a normally white and normally black LCD?

Tags: lcd

I'm trying to understand if there are any differences between a normally white and black LCD, from an appearance standpoint. Does a normally black and normally white just show their respective color when the LCD is powered on by default? Can a normally white screen show black text?

Comment: The only difference I've found when using these is if you use a "normally white" LCD, the border will always be white no matter what's on the screen.  Likewise, if you use "normally black", the border will be black.   The actual active area doesn't look any different.

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, negative (white characters on black background) displays *without backlight* are harder to read since the characters are dimmer.  Without a backlight, the brightness of the displayed characters is due to incident light reflecting off of the backing.  If the entire remainder of the display is blacked out, there's less light available to make the characters look brighter.  If you have a backlight, this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a normally-xxxx display can display the opposite of xxxx.

There shouldn't be any visual differences, as they are the same display.

Interesting trick: remove the [polarizing sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer) in a LCD monitor, and fashion them into a pair of "reading" glasses.  When the monitor is on, it appears totally white to everyone else.  But when you wear the glasses, the image is visible normally. Magic!  Well, not really, but to those uninitiated in optical polarization and interference, it can seem rather mind-boggling.

Even more interesting: rotate your head 90 degrees and the image will appear 100% negative.

So that's the difference between one and the other display - 90 degrees of rotation in the polarizer film produces a perceived "negative" output.